# SP Approval Workflow error when publishing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services, designer-workflow, visio

I have developed an Approval Workflow in Visio and imported into SharePoint Designer. After I finished with the configurations of WF in SPD, I have attempted to publish. Each time I have received an error that states:

**"InfoPath Forms Services support feature is not present"**

I have de-activated/activated the SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features under the Site Collection/Site Features for my particular site. Also, have restarted the server and still has been unsuccessful at correcting the problem

Comment: Resolved this error. Made sure the InfoPath Forms were generating correctly and viewed. Once they generated everything published successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason why this was happening. I had to make sure the InfoPath Service was activated and the forms were being loaded to the Forms Library in Central Admin